# Integrating a Dirac delta function with the argument dependent of a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory

How can I handle the integral

$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta(D - x(t)) dt,
$$

with $D$ a constant. I want to do a change of variables to perform the integral over $x$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Consider this property of the Dirac delta: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function

Comment: Suppose that $x(t) = D$ *once* over the interval of integration.  Now, suppose that $x(t) = D$ *n* times over the interval.  *But*, now suppose that $x(t) = D$ over a continuous subset of the interval...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta(D - x(t)) dt = \int_{t=t_1}^{t_2} \delta(D - x(t))\frac{dx(t)}{|x'(t)|} = \sum_{t:x(t)=D\wedge t\in[t_1,t_2]}\frac{1}{|x'(t)|}.
$$